# Can we deploy SSIS packages (which are created in 2019) to SQL Server 2016?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016

Advice please, can we deploy SSIS packages (which are created in VS2019) to SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Yes. Search the internet for "SSIS property `TargetServerVersion`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, just change TargetServerVersion.
[image: Project properties]